# Use of quotes when running commands on a remote machine using ssh

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I have a command that I know works correctly when I remote into a machine and run it.  The command is below:

```
grep "SearchTerm        $1" file.txt | sed 's/^.*SearchTerm  $1,//g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

But, when I try to run the command from my local computer using `ssh`, it no longer works. I think it's due to my use of quotes, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to fix it.  Any suggestions?

```
ssh username@hostname 'grep "SearchTerm        $1" file.txt | sed 's/^.*SearchTerm  $1,//g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr'
```

Answer (score 0):

$1 is the first argument to a script and you are not passing an argument to it in the example above..  You could make this work by either making a file_count.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@host "grep \"SearchTerm        $1\" file.txt \
| sed 's/^.*SearchTerm  $1,//g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"
```

or another idea is to make a bash alias (or equivalent with your shell):

```
bash$ search_count() { ssh user@host "grep \"SearchTerm        $1\" file.txt \
| sed 's/^.*SearchTerm  $1,//g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr"; }

bash$ search_count wally
      5 SearchTerm        wally
```